# NSTableView bound to NSSearchField - How to relate selection to unfiltered datasource

Tags: nstableview, nssearchfield

I'm stumped.  My Swift app uses an NSTableView bound to an array controller, and uses a bound NSSearchField as a text filter.  My problem is that the table's selectionIndexes binding gives me the selected indexes in the filtered table, whereas I need the selected indexes in the unfiltered table.

Example... my table has 1000 rows and I want to select row 567.  Rather than scroll down to row 567, I enter a few characters into the search box, and this reduces the number of rows to 17, and the row I'm interested in is now row 12.  If I select row 12, how can my app figure out that row 12 corresponds to row 567 in my data array?

Comment: Do you really need the indexes or do you want to get the objects?

Comment: Objects would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectionIndexes` of `NSArrayController` are indexes in `arrangedObjects` of the arrayController. `arrangedObjects` is the content of the arrayController, filtered by `filterPredicate` and sorted by `sortDescriptors`.

Comment: Thanks! It was not clear to me from the limited documentation that arrangedObjects was post-filtered.  Works perfectly now.